# AWS CLI install failure on macOS Mojave

Tags: amazon-web-services, installation, command-line-interface

I am having trouble installing the AWS CLI using the bundled installer as per Amazon instructions.

I get the following error.

```
    MacBook-2:Downloads username$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
Password:
Running cmd: /usr/bin/python virtualenv.py --no-download --python /usr/bin/python /usr/local/aws
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file:///Users/username/Downloads/awscli-bundle/packages/setup setuptools_scm-1.15.7.tar.gz
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file:///Users/username/Downloads/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.16.162.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 162, in <module>
    main()
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 151, in main
    pip_install_packages(opts.install_dir)
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 119, in pip_install_packages
    pip_script, PACKAGES_DIR, cli_tarball))
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 49, in run
    p.returncode, cmd, stdout + stderr))
__main__.BadRCError: Bad rc (1) for cmd '/usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file:///Users/username/Downloads/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.16.162.tar.gz': Looking in links: file:///Users/duncangroenewald/Downloads/awscli-bundle/packages
Processing ./awscli-1.16.162.tar.gz
Collecting botocore==1.12.152 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting colorama<=0.3.9,>=0.2.5 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting PyYAML<=3.13,>=3.10 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from botocore==1.12.152->awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore==1.12.152->awscli==1.16.162)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for setuptools

MacBook-2:Downloads username$ aws
-bash: aws: command not found
MacBook-2:Downloads username$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
Password:
Running cmd: /usr/bin/python virtualenv.py --no-download --python /usr/bin/python /usr/local/aws
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file:///Users/username/Downloads/awscli-bundle/packages/setup setuptools_scm-1.15.7.tar.gz
Running cmd: /usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file:///Users/username/Downloads/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.16.162.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 162, in <module>
    main()
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 151, in main
    pip_install_packages(opts.install_dir)
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 119, in pip_install_packages
    pip_script, PACKAGES_DIR, cli_tarball))
  File "./awscli-bundle/install", line 49, in run
    p.returncode, cmd, stdout + stderr))
__main__.BadRCError: Bad rc (1) for cmd '/usr/local/aws/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links file:///Users/username/Downloads/awscli-bundle/packages awscli-1.16.162.tar.gz': Looking in links: file:///Users/duncangroenewald/Downloads/awscli-bundle/packages
Processing ./awscli-1.16.162.tar.gz
Collecting botocore==1.12.152 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting colorama<=0.3.9,>=0.2.5 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting PyYAML<=3.13,>=3.10 (from awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from botocore==1.12.152->awscli==1.16.162)
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore==1.12.152->awscli==1.16.162)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for setuptools

MacBook-2:Downloads username$
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: `pip install awscli` - preferably inside a virtualenv

Comment: Thanks, it seems Amazons recommenced way is problematic !

Comment: The official https://aws.amazon.com/cli/ page says `pip install awscli`. Where did you see the other instructions?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-macos.html

Comment: Interesting! The bundled installer is apparently self-contained and can be used offline, whereas `pip install` needs to be online.

Comment: FWIW CLI 2 install fails on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.